# Error Can't get a folder under box.net using sharpbox

Tags: c#, cloud, dropbox, box-api

i created some code to get a folder from box.NET using the method GetFolder( ) of the CloudStorage object. but when i ran it gave a NullReferenceExeption and i dont know what is the problem. the code work fine for Dropbox. by the way there is no problem with Box.NET credential since i managed to successfully open the connection to Box.NET.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: The `box-api` tag should be added to this question. There's a suggested edit already in progress, so I can't add it at the moment.

Answer (score 4):

If you're still looking into the problem, I just had to debug it myself.

I kept overlooking the problem as the goof is so minor, but check out `BoxNetStorageProviderServices.cs`.

`OnNameBase` assumes a url will arrive as `http` rather than `https`.  The string replace then changes the url from `https://www.box.com/dav/blahblah` to `httpss://www.box.com/dav/blahblah`.

After adding a tiny bit of logic, everything works great.

Answer (score 1):

Which library are you using?  There is a Box C# library that Box provides the basic tools to get you using the Box apis:  https://github.com/box/box-csharp-sdk

You will also get more help from a broader Box community if you tag this question with the box-api tag.